# Refactoring for Redux/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've been working on a small project for the last of months now involving using functional components and hooks to make an API call and extract some data and do something things with said data. I started with have 1 file that held 3 components in it and was based on classes. I moved everything to functional components and slowly started to build more files. Now, I'm on to my final part of learning React on the side and that comes with Redux. I was wondering if anyone could give me some advice on where to start refactoring my code for Redux and any useful tools out there that may help me along the way. At its core this is a small project but I want to keep the code evolving much like I've evolved through out this. 
Below is a component and a .services that handles the API call. This is basically the whole project in a nutshell.

HeroDetails.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import "../App.css"
import {fetchHeroDetail} from './services/HeroDetail.services'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'


function HeroDetail() {
    const { id } = useParams()
    const [hero, setHero] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
         fetchHeroDetail(id).then(hero => {
            setHero(hero);

        });
    }, [id]);



    return(
        <div>
           <h1>{hero.localized_name} </h1>
            <h2>{hero.move_speed}</h2>
            <h2>{hero.base_health}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default HeroDetail
```

HeroDetail.services.js

```
import React from 'react'

export const fetchHeroDetail = async (id) => {
    const data = await fetch(`https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats`)
    console.log(data)
    const heroDetails = await data.json()
    console.log(heroDetails)
    console.log(heroDetails.find(heroDetail => heroDetail.id === +id))
    return heroDetails.find(heroDetail => heroDetail.id === +id)

};
```

Comment: Start here: https://github.com/alexnm/re-ducks, what you're specifically looking for on that page is an [operation](https://github.com/alexnm/re-ducks#operations) (complexQuack)

Comment: @Adam have you looked at the redux starter kit? i think that's gone quite far beyond your link at this point. start with the docs ! https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Comment: @azium - I've been trapped in projects where people organized them very poorly for a long time (stick all your actions together, stick all your reducers together, mix everything together and let insanity ensue). If you're going to learn what redux is, might as well start with a well architected form of redux. At the same time. OP should definitely refer to the redux documentation to understand core concepts, but when it comes to "creating a redux project" start with the proper scaffolding - `reducks`

Comment: also, many people recommend redux-toolkit: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/